# pandas json_normalize flatten nested dictionaries

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to flatten nested dictionaries by using `json_normalize`.
My data is like this:

```
data = [
    {'gra': [
        {
            'A': 1,
            'B': 9,
            'C': {'D': '1', 'E': '1'},
            'date': '2019-06-27'
        }
    ]},
    {'gra': [
        {
            'A': 2,
            'B': 1,
            'C': {'D': '1', 'E': '2'},
            'date': '2019-06-27'
        }
    ]},
    {'gra': [
        {
            'A': 6,
            'B': 1,
            'C': {'D': '1', 'E': '3'},
            'date': '2019-06-27'
        }
    ]}
]
```

I want to get a dataframe like this:

```
A   B    C.D   C.E       date
1   9     1     1     2019-06-27
2   1     1     2     2019-06-27
6   1     1     3     2019-06-27
```

I tried `record_path` and `meta` in the `json_normalize`, but it keeps giving me an error.

How do you achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> json_normalize does a pretty good job of flatting the object into a
>   pandas dataframe:
>
> ```
> from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
> json_normalize(sample_object)
> ```

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
data_ = [item['gra'][0] for item in data] # [{'A': 1, 'B': 9, 'C': {'D': '1', 'E': '1'}, 'date': '2019-06-27'}, {'A': 2, 'B': 1, 'C': {'D': '1', 'E': '2'}, 'date': '2019-06-27'}, {'A': 6, 'B': 1, 'C': {'D': '1', 'E': '3'}, 'date': '2019-06-27'}]

print (json_normalize(data_))
```

output:

```
   A  B C.D C.E        date
0  1  9   1   1  2019-06-27
1  2  1   1   2  2019-06-27
2  6  1   1   3  2019-06-27
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the most easy way by iterating the list but cannot say it is the best way.

I hope it would solve your problem

```
data = [{'gra':[{'A': 1,
                        'B': 9,
                        'C': {'D': '1', 'E': '1'},
                        'date': '2019-06-27'}]},
        {'gra':[{'A': 2,
                         'B': 1,
                         'C': {'D': '1', 'E': '2'},
                         'date': '2019-06-27'}]},
        {'gra':[{'A': 6,
                         'B': 1,
                         'C': {'D': '1', 'E': '3'},
                         'date': '2019-06-27'}]}
        ]
final_list =[]
for i in data:
    temp = dict()
    temp['A'] = i['gra'][0]['A']
    temp['B'] = i['gra'][0]['B']
    temp['C.D'] = i['gra'][0]['C']['D']
    temp['C.E'] = i['gra'][0]['C']['E']
    temp['date']=i['gra'][0]['date']
    final_list.append(temp)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(final_list)

print(df)
```

```
   A  B C.D C.E        date
0  1  9   1   1  2019-06-27
1  2  1   1   2  2019-06-27
2  6  1   1   3  2019-06-27
```

Answer (score 0):

First we normalized and then hacked our way to produce the required output

```
import pandas as pd 

data = [
    {'gra': [
        {
            'A': 1,
            'B': 9,
            'C': {'D': '1', 'E': '1'},
            'date': '2019-06-27'
        }
    ]},
    {'gra': [
        {
            'A': 2,
            'B': 1,
            'C': {'D': '1', 'E': '2'},
            'date': '2019-06-27'
        }
    ]},
    {'gra': [
        {
            'A': 6,
            'B': 1,
            'C': {'D': '1', 'E': '3'},
            'date': '2019-06-27'
        }
    ]}
]

df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'gra')

cols = ['A','B','C.D','C.E','date']
df = df[cols]

print(df)
```

```
A  B C.D C.E        date
0  1  9   1   1  2019-06-27
1  2  1   1   2  2019-06-27
2  6  1   1   3  2019-06-27

[Program finished]
```